# Flutter - ListView not updating after adding item to list on Android

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am trying to update the ListView
In the onPressed function of the add button I have added the new Todo in the todos list using setState function. But on android it does not work. On iOS it works fine.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: todos.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {},
          title: Text(todos[index].text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);

onPressed: () async {
  Todo newTodo = Todo(text: todoText);
  newTodo.insert();
  setState(() {
    todos.add(newTodo);
  });
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is Keys.
From [the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro#keys),

> Keys are most useful in widgets that build many instances of the same type of widget. For example, the ShoppingList widget, which builds just enough ShoppingListItem instances to fill its visible region:
>
> Without keys, the first entry in the current build would always sync with the first entry in the previous build, even if, semantically, the first entry in the list just scrolled off screen and is no longer visible in the viewport.
>
> By assigning each entry in the list a “semantic” key, the infinite list can be more efficient because the framework syncs entries with matching semantic keys and therefore similar (or identical) visual appearances. Moreover, syncing the entries semantically means that state retained in stateful child widgets remains attached to the same semantic entry rather than the entry in the same numerical position in the viewport.

Update your code to see if this works,

You should update your todo item

```dart
new Todo(text, key:Key(text))
```

When inserting a new todo,

```dart
todos.add(
  new Todo(text, key:Key("$text")))
```

Another way to specify a random key is

```dart
child: ListView.builder(
    key: Key(randomString()),
```